# store procedure with parameter in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
create procedure insert_income(@title varchar(45),@category varchar(45),@amount float,@date `datetime,@type varchar(45))
as 
begin
  declare @id int(11)
  declare @bal int(11)
  set @id= select max(id) from income;
  set @bal=select balance from income where id=@id;
  if(@category='INCOME')
    begin
      set @bal=@bal+@amount
      insert into income values(@title,@date,@category,@amount,@bal,@type)
    end
  else
    begin
      if(@category='EXPENSES')
        begin
        set @bal=@bal-@amount
        insert into income values(@title,@date,@category,@amount,@bal,@type)
        end
    end
  end
```

I had written the procedure for Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008 now I need to write this in MYSQL

Comment: Did you try on `MySQL`? You got errors? Post them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes suggested**:  to export the same into `MySQL` database

- When you have multiple statements to be executed as part of a stored
  procedure, define a custom `delimiter` like `delimiter //` so that
  the engine won't execute a statement when it finds a default
  statement terminator `;`.
- Remove `@` qualifier on input parameters for the procedure.
- All code body must be enclosed within `begin` - `end` block. It is
  optional in case if the number of executable statements are single.
- Each executable statement must be set end with a default *statement
  terminator*, `;`.
- All `if` conditions must have a `then` clause after the condition.
- `else if` and `elseif` are different. For each of extra `if` also
  should end with a `end if;`.
- All `if` blocks must end with a `end if;`
- Block or scope specific `begin` - `end` are optional unless a scope
  variable you want to declare in that code block.
- Now reset the `delimiter` to its default like `delimiter ;`.

**Refer to**:

- [MySQL Stored Procedures (PDF)](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.pdf)
- [MySQL: Create Procedure Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)